# How read the current upstream for a git branch

Tags: git, git-branch, upstream-branch

I'm searching a git command to know the upstream associated with an existing branch (if any).
(some kind of "read" command associated with the "write" command `git branch --set-upstream-to=...`)
The reason is I use a branch connected with several remote repos, and I'd like to check if the branch is already connected with the right upstream before changing it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### TL;DR: use `git rev-parse`

```
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref master@{u}
weird/master
```

If no upstream is set, you get:

```
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
```

(and a nonzero exit code).  Redirect stderr to `/dev/null` to discard the error message if you don't want it:

```
if master_upstream=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref master@{u} 2>/dev/null); then
    master_has_upstream=true
else
    master_has_upstream=false
fi
```

for instance.

#### Explanation

[Anthony Sottile's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46515157/1256452) *usually* gets you the correct name, but not quite always.  In particular, watch what happens when the `remote.origin.fetch` setting for `origin` is not the norm:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in .../tmp/tt/.git/
$ git remote add origin git://github.com/git/git
$ git config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/weird/*'
$ git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 231294, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (663/663), done.
remote: Total 231294 (delta 0), reused 662 (delta 0), pack-reused 230631
Receiving objects: 100% (231294/231294), 93.03 MiB | 3.54 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (170261/170261), done.
From git://github.com/git/git
 * [new branch]          maint      -> weird/maint
 * [new branch]          master     -> weird/master
 * [new branch]          next       -> weird/next
 * [new branch]          pu         -> weird/pu
 * [new branch]          todo       -> weird/todo
 * [new tag]             v2.14.2    -> v2.14.2
[lots more tags snipped]
```

Note that while the *remote* is named `origin`, the remote-tracking *branches* are named `weird/master`, `weird/next`, and so on.  And it actually works:

```
$ git checkout master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Already on 'master'
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'weird/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

But what's in `.git/config` still looks like you would expect if the remote-tracking branch name were `origin/master`:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Using:

```
 branch="$(git branch | grep '\*' | cut -d' ' -f2-)"
```

works well enough (although one should often use `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` to get the current branch name: see below).

```
remote="$(git config "branch.${branch}.remote")"
```

This part works perfectly—it gets the name of the remote.

```
remote_branch="$(git config "branch.${branch}.merge" | cut -d/ -f3-)"
```

This is where we go wrong.  What we need is to use `git rev-parse` plus the gitrevisions syntax for "the upstream of a specified branch", which is to append `@{u}` or `@{upstream}` to the branch name.  Normally `git rev-parse` turns this into a hash ID, but with `--abbrev-ref`, it prints a short version of the name, or with `--symbolic-full-name`, it prints the long version:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
refs/remotes/weird/master
```

(I have no idea why this is spelled `--abbrev-ref` in one case and `--symbolic-full-name` in another.)

Note that when using `git rev-parse` on `HEAD`, if `HEAD` is detached, the answer is the symbol `HEAD`.  That is, in any Git repository, `git rev-parse HEAD` always succeeds, even when printing symbolic names.  This is *not* true for `git symbolic-ref` though:

```
$ git checkout --detach
HEAD is now at ea220ee40... The eleventh batch for 2.15
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
HEAD
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD
HEAD
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
```

So for resolving `HEAD` (to find the current branch), choose which command to use based on the behavior you want in the "no current branch" case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's very cler and detailled. For my part, default remote repos are always called `origin` so I will use your syntax `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref 'mybranch'@{upstream}`

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I found the same answer as `git status` but in a script-friendly way:

```
 $ branch="$(git branch | grep '\*' | cut -d' ' -f2-)"
 $ remote="$(git config "branch.${branch}.remote")"
 $ remote_branch="$(git config "branch.${branch}.merge" | cut -d/ -f3-)"
 $ echo "${branch} is tracking ${remote}/${remote_branch}"
 print_locking_less is tracking origin/master
```

The information for remote tracking branch is stored in `.git/config`, it looks like this:

```
[branch "print_locking_less"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: It is nice but tricky a lot. I deeply prefer torek's solution ! But thank's for the information about the file `.git/config` it is interesting too.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `git branch -vv`:

```
foo    03b325f Commit on untracked branch
master b7da42b [origin/master] Initial commit
```

The upstream (if any) is nicely displayed in square brackets.

Excerpt from the [manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---verbose) with emphasis added:

> -v
> -vv
> --verbose
> When in list mode, show sha1 and commit subject line for each head, along with relationship to upstream branch (if any).
> ***If given twice, print the path of the linked worktree (if any) and the***
> ***name of the upstream branch***, as well (see also git remote show
> ). Note that the current worktree’s HEAD will not have its
> path printed (it will always be your current directory).

Note that `-vv` is more verbose than `--verbose` which is the same as `-v`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I found a first trick using `git status` commmand :
I the branch is the current branch and have an upstream, I get a line like `Your branch is up-to-date with 'the_repo/the branch'`, but I'rather have a more direct way to know that.